# How to fix the mutex lock?

Tags: android, multithreading, mutex, android-anr-dialog

Google play has reported an ANR in my application, following is a snippet of the log associated with the ANR,

```
"HeapTaskDaemon" daemon prio=5 tid=6 Blocked
  | group="system" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x12c9bc40 self=0xb93a6020
  | sysTid=15299 nice=0 cgrp=default sched=0/0 handle=0xb40ed930
  | state=S schedstat=( 0 0 0 ) utm=6793 stm=227 core=0 HZ=100
  | stack=0xb3feb000-0xb3fed000 stackSize=1038KB
  | held mutexes=
  native: pc 0000000000016a5c  /system/lib/libc.so (syscall+32)
  native: pc 00000000000f6ed9  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art17ConditionVariable9TimedWaitEPNS_6ThreadExi+120)
  native: pc 00000000001d7265  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art2gc13TaskProcessor7GetTaskEPNS_6ThreadE+240)
  native: pc 00000000001d7711  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art2gc13TaskProcessor11RunAllTasksEPNS_6ThreadE+72)
  native: pc 000000000000037f  /data/dalvik-cache/arm/system@framework@boot.oat (Java_dalvik_system_VMRuntime_runHeapTasks__+74)
  at dalvik.system.VMRuntime.runHeapTasks (Native method)
- waiting to lock an unknown object
  at java.lang.Daemons$HeapTaskDaemon.run (Daemons.java:355)
  at java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:818)
```

Please throw some insight into how to get this fixed.

Note :- 
You can find the entire crash log at this link :-

https://pastebin.com/pxzLLnBt

Comment: It is not main thread, so you should have other stacktrace. ANR is only when main thread cannot refresh UI, but it's a daemon.

Comment: @barwnikk Please check the updated question